# Implementing news filter in MQL4 programs

Tags: mql4, forex

Am trying to implement a news filter in a FOREX robot am creating an using MQL4.

My main issue is getting the news and the time it'll occur. I've seen posts that suggests using ffcal indicator. However I want a more direct approach. I want to get the news details and have the EA (robot) process them on a case by case bases.

Any ideas on how to achieve this or something similar will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

### Doable . . .

Best, yet, outside the MQL4/5 **`QUOTE`**-stream event-loop `OnTick(){...}` event-handler.

---

### Any idea ?

One may create a persistent autonomous News-[Collector|Processor|Analyser|TradingResponder] pipeline and let MQL4/5 EA-s just ask and reflect the `TradingResponder`-delivered advice.

This way your intention will not block / deteriorate the MetaTrader Terminal platform processing stability and your trading infrastructure may enjoy distributed architecture performance and robustness if one will.

Having a similar architecture implemented and operated for an externalised QuantFX-processing of both TA and FA input factors ( yes, also the News ), there is **less than about `~ < 80 [ms]` Turn-Around-Time** to jump into XTO after receiving each `QUOTE`-event, so if your target is not under HFT-grade latency-tresholds of TAT << units of `[us]`, you may enjoy the same.